# What are the percentages above the alien icon?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

When a unit sees an alien, an alien icon appears on the bottom right corner of the screen. When the mother hovers over it a percentage appears. The percentage is sometimes different from the chance to hit (like in the picture). What does that percentage represents?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm fairly certain the incorrect values in the lower right are a bug/defect in the game.  Occasionally I've witnessed multiple alien targets all showing as 1%, despite being in the open with no cover.  I have not conducted extensive testing to confirm, but I believe the values that appear when targeting the creature (top center in the image) are correct.

Comment: Considering all the bugs, I think so too if it does say 1% all the time.

Comment: Certain Heavies of mine always display 1% regardless of the situation. They still hit things though.

Comment: Huh. This happens to me most of the time, and not only with 1%, but with all kinds of weird percentages. It's more often wrong than right. I have to cycle through all the enemies just to find the best shot, since the icon percentages seem completely random. It was the most glaring and persistent bug I encountered throughout the game. And that's with a fully up-to-date steam version more than two months after release.